# How to edit a datevalue with a textfield

Tags: datetime, extjs, extjs6

Since ExtJs is missing a datetime field, I figured the easiest way to edit a datetime value in a grid was to use a textfield. I didn't find a simple example that validates the field and updates the record transparently for the user.

This is the column in my grid, where I want to add my editor

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.grid.DateEdit', {
    columns: [{
        text: 'Datetime value', 
        dataIndex: 'mydatetime', 
        xtype:'datecolumn', 
        format: 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
    }]
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a minimalistic approach, that handles validation and date to string conversion transparently for the user:

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.grid.DateEdit', {
    columns: [{
        text: 'Datetime value', 
        dataIndex: 'mydatetime', 
        xtype:'datecolumn', 
        format: 'Y-m-d H:i:s',
        editor: {
            xtype:'textfield',
            errorMessage: 'Invalid date format',
            format: 'Y-m-d H:i:s',
            validator: function(val){return val.match(/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/) ? true : this.errorMessage},
            valueToRaw: function(val){return Ext.Date.format(val, this.format)},
            rawToValue: function(val){return Ext.Date.parse(val, this.format)}
        }
    }]
})
```